# Python 3/Pygame syntax error defining function

Tags: python, pygame, syntax-error

I get a syntax error every time I run the code.  I've checked multiple times for errors and checked online for a solution, but I couldn't find anything.  Tell me if you need more of the code, here is the function that the error popped up on and the Error:

```
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont('Tabatha_Regular.ttf',105)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Tower Defense Thing", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button("Play",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


    def game_intro():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please post the complete, unedited traceback.

Comment: You should also look at the code *before* the line where it looks like there's an error.  People often forget to close parentheses, which results in a SyntaxError as soon as the code can no longer be interpreter as valid Python, even if that line looks fine on its own.

Comment: @DSM That solved the problem.  If you couldn't guess, I am pretty new to Pygame / Python.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

1. You can't just simply `def game_intro():` without stating the body of the function. Give it a `pass` at least.
2. Why game_intro is defined twice? And in a embedded way?

Comment: the second     def game_intro():     was part of the error I got, not part of the code.  I should have separated it from the code, sorry for the confusion.  Turns out I forgot to close some parentheses before the game_intro.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your indentation at the end and the names of the method